# Quantization minimizing the quadratic error

Tags: algorithms, optimization, computer-science

I am working on a quantization problem which could be express in these terms :

Given a set of positive reals $\{x_1, x_2,\dots,x_M\}$, I need to find another set $\{y_1,y_2,\dots,y_N\}$ of size $N < M$ such that :

$
\left\{ \begin{array}{c}
\forall k\leq M, y_{f(k)}^{2}-x_{k}^{2}\geq0\\
\underset{y,f}{min}\underset{k}{\sum}y_{f(k)}^{2}-x_{k}^{2}
\end{array}\right.
$

What would be a good/fast algorithmic approach to solve this kind of problem ?

Comment: Please define $y_{f(k)}$, what is the relation with $y_k$?

Comment: $f$ is simply a function from $\{0,\dots, M\}$ into $\{0,\dots, N\}$. It is a parameter of the minimisation.

Comment: Are the parameters $\{y_1,y_2,\dots,y_N\}$ fix or are they also optimization varibles? Furthermore, is $f$ a one-to-one function, that is, $f(m) \neq f(n)$ if $n \neq m$?

Comment: Yes ${y_1,y_2,\dots,y_N}$ and $f$ are optimization variables. Futhermore $f$ can't be injective (one to  one) since $M > N$